# How to properly remove multiple event listeners?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

(Obviously this doesn't have much to do with typescript, except that the example code is in ts).

```
import { createWriteStream, WriteStream } from "fs";

export class Util {
    public static openWrite(path: string): Promise<WriteStream> {
        return new Promise<WriteStream>((resolve, reject) => {
            const result = createWriteStream(path);

            const onError = (err: Error) => {
                // How to remove both listeners here?
                reject(err);
            }

            const onOpen = (fd: number) => {
                // How to remove both listeners here?
                resolve(result);
            };

            result.on("error", onError);
            result.on("open", onOpen);
        }); 
    }
}
```

The code should say it all. I have a hard time to see how the function should be written such that it handles both the success and failure scenarios correctly, while ensuring that all added event handlers are removed when everything is done.

Of course, there is always the possibility to call removeAllListeners, but that looks like a hack to me.

Comment: I think it's not possible without removeAllListerners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good use-case for `finally`.

```
let onError, onOpen;
const result = createWriteStream(path);
return new Promise<WriteStream>((resolve, reject) => {

    onError = (err: Error) => {
        // How to remove both listeners here?
        reject(err);
    }

    onOpen = (fd: number) => {
        // How to remove both listeners here?
        resolve(result);
    };

    result.on("error", onError);
    result.on("open", onOpen);
}).finally(() => {
    result.removeListener("error", onError);
    result.removeListener("open", onOpen);
});
```

Or if you know that no other listeners are already attached to the `EventEmitter` you can simplify it as follows:

```
const result = createWriteStream(path);
return new Promise<WriteStream>((resolve, reject) => {
    result.on("error", reject);
    result.on("open", resolve);
}).then(() => {
    return result;
}).finally(() => {
    result.removeAllListeners("error");
    result.removeAllListeners("open");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In NodeJS, all `Stream` is an `EventEmitter` (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream)
The `EventEmitter` has a method called `removeListener`. So try to do the Following:

```
return new Promise<WriteStream>((resolve, reject) => {
    const result = createWriteStream(path);

    const onError = (err: Error) => {
        result.removeAllListeners()
        reject(err);
    }

    const onOpen = (fd: number) => {
        result.removeAllListeners()
        resolve(result);
    }

    result.on("error", onError);
    result.on("open", onOpen);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally went with ...

```
public static async openWrite(path: string): Promise<WriteStream> {
    const factory = new StreamFactory(() => createWriteStream(path));

    try {
        return await factory.get();
    } finally {
        factory.dispose();
    }
}
```

... with StreamFactory defined as follows:

```
class StreamFactory<T extends EventEmitter> {
    private stream: T;
    private onOpen: (fd: number) => void;
    private onError: (err: Error) => void;
    private readonly promise: Promise<T>;

    public constructor(create: () => T) {
        this.promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.stream = create();
            this.onOpen = fd => resolve(this.stream);
            this.onError = err => reject(err);
            this.stream.on("open", this.onOpen).on("error", this.onError); 
        });
    }

    public get(): Promise<T> { return this.promise; }

    public dispose(): void {
        this.stream.removeListener("open", this.onOpen).removeListener("error", this.onError);
    }
}
```

I've tested the failure and success paths of the above and the event handlers are removed correctly in both cases. Of course, this is just a variation of Jakes answer, so +1 to him for pointing this out.

This has the advantage of not resorting to `Promise.finally`, which doesn't seem to be available on my platform (Node 8.x).

It appears that it is definitely not a good idea to use `removeAllListeners()`. At least on my platform, the library itself seems to add a listener for `"open"` when an error occurs. `removeAllListeners()` would remove that with possibly unintended consequences.